# Cassandra: removing keyspace after data center sync?

Tags: cassandra

We are in the process of moving our Cassandra cluster ( *version 1.1.6* ) from our old DC ( *DC2* ) to a new DC ( *DC1* - yes the are reversed) one keyspace at a time.

We have 3 keyspaces *A*, *B* and *C*:

A and B have already been successfully moved to the new datacenter and were running with a replication factor of **DC1:3;DC2:3**. All our applications for these two keyspaces have been updated so that nothing is writing/reading from the old datacenter. We then changed the replication factor to **DC1:3;DC2:0** so the data is now actually stale.

I was trying to find a way to delete these keyspaces in the old DC to free up the space I need for keyspace C, but I haven't found one.

Is there a way of dropping a keyspace from a singe data center, or better work around for removing the data from the old DC?

Comment: Did you try changing the replication factor to `{DC1:3}` and there is no DC2?

Comment: Yes, but the data is not removed, even after a `nodetool cleanup A`

Comment: If the data on DC2 does not matter, and you have already changed the setting so that there will be no communication with DC2 for the data, I think you can just go ahead and delete the keyspace `A` directory in the `data_directory` on all the machines in DC2. This should theoretically be fine.

Comment: @Nishant: you are correct, theoretically it should work. I stopped cassandra (because of the open files), removed the directory and started again, and cassandra as well as our apps had no problems. Thanks!

Comment: great. Converting it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the replication factor to `{DC1:3}`. Note that there is no `DC2`.

If the data on `DC2` does not matter, and you have already changed the setting so that there will be no communication with `DC2` for the data, I think you can just go ahead and delete the keyspace `A` directory in the `data_directory` on all the machines in `DC2`. This should theoretically be fine.